# Python BOTO3 script is not returning name inside the tag

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I need to extract the name, instance id, state of AWS EC2 and export it to csv. By using the below code I got the instance id and state. The name is inside the tags and I am having multiple key-value in my tags like below:

"Tags": [
{
"Value": "ggggg",
"Key": "bbbb"
},
{
"Value": "rrrrrr",
"Key": "eeeee"
},
{
"Value": "uyyyutu",
"Key": "hhhhhh"
},
{
"Value": "xxxxxxx",
"Key": "NAME"
},
{
"Value": "GREEN",
"Key": "STATE"
},
{
"Value": "xxxxx",
"Key": "yyyyy"
}
]

How can I get the name from particular KEY=NAME. While using the following code I am getting all values in the tags it is not giving particular value.

```
import boto3
import csv

client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
        'Name':'tag:STATE','Values':['GREEN']
        }
    ]
)

detail=[]

for Reservations in response["Reservations"]:
    for Instances in Reservations["Instances"]:
        detail.append({
            'ID':Instances['InstanceId'],
            'Status':Instances['State']['Name'],
            'Name':Instances['Tags']['Key'=='Name']['Value']
        })

header=['ID','Status','Name']
with open('EC2_Detail.csv','w') as file:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(detail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[x for x in Instances['Tags'] if x['Key'] == 'NAME'][0]['Value']
```

This will break, if the tag name isn't defined for a specific instance.

```
tag_names = [x for x in Instances['Tags'] if x['Key'] == 'NAME']
if len(tag_names) > 0: name = tag_names[0]
```

Comment: Thanks @kgiannakakis got Name, but if I try to get multiple values from tag it gives indexerror: IndexError: list index out of range. Code is here:
 ` 'Name':[x for x in Instances['Tags'] if x['Key'] == 'NAME'][0]['Value'], 'Env':[x for x in Instances['Tags'] if x['Key'] == 'ENVIRONMENT'][0]['Value'], 'Rel':[x for x in Instances['Tags'] if x['Key'] == 'RELEASE'][0]['Value'], 'Data':[x for x in Instances['Tags'] if x['Key'] == 'data'][0]['Value'] `

Comment: Name tag is always there, so it is safe to index at 0. For other tag keys, you should check that there is a value first.